# How can I move elements into view when the window is resized?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a project which I need to do an aquarium and the fishes inside gather on click.

I have done everything, but here is the problem, the program should work on resize.

What I am trying to say. If I resize the browser window, the fishes should re-appear in the visible spot of the window and continue swimming.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    body{background-color:aqua; width:100%; height:100%;padding:0; margin:0;}
    img{width:50px; height:50px;}
    div{position:absolute;}
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    i = 0;

    function swim(fishid){
    newLeft = Math.random()*1200; // due to new width
    newTop = Math.random()*600; //due to new height
    do_move(fishid, newTop, newLeft, Math.random()*1000);
    }

  function do_move(fishid, topPos, leftPos, timeToMove=0){
    $("#"+fishid).css({"transform": "rotateY(0deg)"});
    ll = leftPos + 'px';
    tt = topPos + 'px';
    if( parseInt($("#"+fishid).css('left'))>leftPos){
        $("#"+fishid).css({"transform": "rotateY(180deg)"});
    }
    $("#"+fishid).animate({"left": ll, "top": tt}, 1000+timeToMove, function(){swim(fishid);});
  }

    $(document).ready(function(){
    let fishes = Math.random()*5+5;
    for(i=0; i<fishes; i++){
     $("body").append('<div id="fish'+ i + '"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/256/Animals-Fish-icon.png"></div>');
      swim("fish" + i);
    }
    $("*").click(function(ev){
      $("div").each(function(){
        $(this).stop();
        do_move($(this).attr("id"), ev.pageY-25, ev.pageX);
       });
    });
      $ ( window ).resize(function(){});// I have to do it with this also
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make it easy on people and post a semi-working version somewhere.

Comment: It depends on the screen, I have set the defaults to:
newLeft = Math.random()*1200;
newTop = Math.random()*600;

Comment: Also, you have a pile of global variables (defined without `let` or `const`). That's not best practice.

Comment: How are you detecting resize?

Answer (score 0):

Use the actual window dimensions instead of hard-coded values:

```
newLeft = Math.random() * window.innerWidth * 0.9;
newTop = Math.random() * window.innerHeight * 0.9;
```

No resize event handler is needed since the `swim()` function is called repeatedly. This means that there's a brief period where fish can escape the window, but it's resolved after one program cycle. Putting `overflow: hidden` on the body eliminates scrollbars during resize.

I've introduced an arbitrary reducer of 90% to allow for fish size. That could be adjusted.

[**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ho6qg0jk/)

Answer (score 0):

The resize event will be triggered whenever you resize your screen. You can easily get the screens inner width and height similarly.

```
$(window).resize(function(e){
  console.log($(this).innerWidth())
  console.log($(this).innerHeight())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newLeft = Math.random() *$( window ).width(); 
newTop = Math.random() *$( window ).height()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rkv88/nh1buw8o/